# Sollice statspump schema errors when connecting to message VPN

Tags: solace

I am trying to set up StatsPump and StatsReciever from Solace. I have already set up a VMR on my machine using docker. Trying to connect to it using StatsPump but am running into "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Have not loaded schemas for 'soltr/8
    _12VMR". Here is the log from the statspump.log file.

```
2018-09-06T16:30:05,392 [Poll_Thread_00004] INFO  c.s.p.e.s.PhysicalAppliance - SEMP version of 'localhost:808
0' changing from '~UNINITIALIZED~' to 'soltr/8_12VMR'
2018-09-06T16:30:05,393 [Poll_Thread_00000] ERROR c.s.p.e.s.ScheduledPollerHandle - Caught this while waiting
for Poller 'show hostname' on localhost:8080
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Have not loaded schemas for 'soltr/8
_12VMR'. Ensure schema version looks like 'soltr/x_y'. Call loadSchemas() first, or import new schema files.
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[?:1.8.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_71]
        at com.solace.psg.enterprisestats.statspump.ScheduledPollerHandle$PollerWatcherTask.call(ScheduledPoll
erHandle.java:62) [solace-statspump-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at com.solace.psg.enterprisestats.statspump.ScheduledPollerHandle.oneTimePoller(ScheduledPollerHandle.
java:221) [solace-statspump-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at com.solace.psg.enterprisestats.statspump.ReachableRunnable.run(ReachableRunnable.java:59) [solace-s
tatspump-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
```

Comment: I don't see this software under https://dev.solace.com/downloads/ --- it looks like a controlled-availability software. Perhaps you can consider raising the question to support@solace.com.